# Using Lattitude and Longitude json data, how to place pins on 3D Globe?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 3D Globe of Earth (sphere with radius 20), and json file which content few locations with latitude and longitude values.

How could i map these lat+long values to place pin icon on to the globe?

Thanks,
Chetan

Comment: You mean you don't know how to convert the polar coordinates (lat, lon, radius) to cartesian coordinates (x, y, z)? See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates

Comment: Thanks Clemens, let me check